# Reinstall "Google Play services"

Tags: google-play-services

I have deleted Google Play services on my Android cell phone. While trying to reinstall from google, I have "No Carrier Lenovo 860t) and can not install.
Please can you kindly help me on this, what is "no carrier" means and how to fix it ?
Thank you,

My phone : Lenovo 860t (China made)
Android 4.4.2 Kit Kat

Answer (score 2):

Google Play Services has to be installed as a system application. Assuming you have properly *uninstalled* that application, you have to copy the `.apk` file back to where it should be (probably `/system/app` or `/system/priv-app`).

To that *No Carrier* thing: This just means that your device didn't send Google any Information about the carrier that you have and that you should use the normal, non carrier-specific store (There are different stores with some extra applications/different listings for specific countries and even carriers).

Answer (score 0):

You can get back your Play Services, just by downloading Google Play Store, it will automatically download the Google Play Services, In many devices, only play store comes by default,not the play services, when you connect your google account,to play store, it will download the play services.

Download Play Store : http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-store/